# some strange layout using only ul/li elements with different height

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to create the following layout using ul/li elements (I mean using some normal way, without some strange hacks)?

[image]

All elements in red has the same width.

**Why I want to use ul/li elements?**

All over the page there are ul/li elements for very similar layout, but where all items are the same widtha and height. So the style already exists for seperate li element (it has some particular background, inside each li are some elements whose styles are already defined as child elements of li etc.). So this is the reason why I am asking this.
A good point in commenst was that I can use classes to achieve the same style. I will update css for this.

**If I cannot use ul/li, what is the best approach to achieve this kind of layout?**

Comment: If you must use ul/li elements, I cannot help you. But if you are not, try jQuery Masonry plugin http://masonry.desandro.com/. You can make something like http://erikjohanssonphoto.com/work/imagecats/personal/.

Comment: @Heejin he said that the red boxes are of same size so I think jQuery Masonry wouldn't come in handy here!

Comment: you don't have to use just ul and li's, you can have classes and id's that have the same layout styles

Comment: This is a good point. I will update css to use classes to achieve.

Answer (score 5):

Working example with `li` and `ul` in **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/achudars/ufMEa/)**

[image]